# why does my code not read or follow the if statements?

Tags: c++

Why does my code not read or follow the `if` statements?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    
    int sum = 0;
    int integer;
    
    while ((integer != -1) && (sum < 2000)){
        int integer;
        
        cout<<"Enter an integer: ";
        cin>>integer;

        if (integer == -1){
            cout<<"Program was terminated.\n"<<"Your total sales are: "<<sum<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (sum >= 2000) {
            cout<<"Congratulations!"<<"Your total sales are: "<<sum<<endl;
            break;
        }
        
        sum = sum + integer;
        if (sum > 499){
            cout<<"You're off to a good start!"<<endl;
        }
        if (sum > 999){
            cout<<"You're halfway through!"<<endl;
        }
        else if (sum > 1499){
            cout<<"You're almost there!"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected:
Input looks like:
Enter an interger: 350, 500,800, 500

Then the out should look like:

```
Enter an integer 350
      " "        500
                 youre off to a good start
                 800
                 youre halfway through
                 500
                 Congratualations! Youre total sales are: 2150
```

Reality:

```
Enter an integer: 350
Enter an integer: 500
You're off to a good start!
Enter an integer: 800
You're off to a good start!
You're halfway through!
Enter an integer: 500
You're off to a good start!
You're halfway through!
```

Comment: To begin with: when you hit `while ((integer != -1) && (sum < 2000)){`, `integer` is **uninitialized**. This is UB. Also your `integer` inside the loop shadows the one outside.

Comment: Remove the integer Initialisation inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want only 1 branch to be entered, so you need a `if` `else if` chain.

```
if (sum >= 2000) {
    std::cout << "Congratulations!" << "Your total sales are: " << sum << std::endl;
    break;
}
else if (sum > 1499) {
    std::cout << "You're almost there!" << std::endl;
}
else if (sum > 999) {
    std::cout << "You're halfway through!" << std::endl;
}
else if (sum > 499) {
    std::cout << "You're off to a good start!" << std::endl;
}
```

You have to start with the largest number to the smallest one, since if you go from smaller to larger, if a branch is entered it will *always* be the first branch.

---

```
while ((integer != -1) && (sum < 2000)){
```

this is wrong, as `integer` is not initialiazed and this is therefore undefined behaviour. In some cases it might never enter the while loop because `integer` holds some random garbage value that happens to be `-1`.

You can replace it with a simple while true loop:

```
while (true) {
```

since you are calling `break;` in the final branches anyway (this escapes the `while` loop). This will also fix the bug, that the loop would terminate before the final print outs.

---

```
int integer;

while ((integer != -1) && (sum < 2000)) {
    int integer;
```

you just declared `integer` twice, the second one is not needed.

---

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int integer;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> integer;

        if (integer == -1) {
            std::cout << "Program was terminated.\n" << "Your total sales are: " << sum << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        sum = sum + integer;
        if (sum >= 2000) {
            std::cout << "Congratulations!" << "Your total sales are: " << sum << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (sum > 1499) {
            std::cout << "You're almost there!" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (sum > 999) {
            std::cout << "You're halfway through!" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (sum > 499) {
            std::cout << "You're off to a good start!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

---

read [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)